# Error while installing Apache SparkR package

Tags: r, apache-spark, r-package

I am getting the following error while installing the apache `sparkr` package:

```
install_github("amplab-extras/SparkR-pkg", subdir="pkg")
Downloading github repo amplab-extras/SparkR-pkg@master
Installing SparkR
Error in isNamespaceLoaded(pkg) : 
 attempt to use zero-length variable name
```

Comment: Try to install it from the command line running `sudo R CMD install_github("amplab-extras/SparkR-pkg", subdir="pkg")`

Comment: What version of devtools are you using? What OS, and where is your package library?

Comment: Getting the following error on trying  from "bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('"

Comment: Package devtools version 1.7.0; OS - Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 4):

I was able to load the SparkR library in R/RStudio by doing the following: 
**Download and setup SparkR** 
1. Download spark-1.4.0 and untar/unzip it 
2. Install spark, then go to your directory /spark01.4.0/R 
3. In a terminal, run ./install-dev.sh. This will create a folder called "lib" in your directory

**Add SparkR to R .libPaths()**
4. In a terminal:

```
    cat >> $HOME/.Rprofile <<EOT
    lib_path <- .libPaths()
    lib_path <- c(lib_path,"/MyDirectory/spark-1.4.0/R/lib")
    .libPaths(lib_path)
    rm(lib_path)
    EOT
```

5. Load R, then use library(SparkR).

Answer (score 1):

I've been having the same problem with the `pander` package and managed a long-winded work around. I installed `pander` from Github to an earlier version of R (3.1.2 worked for me). I then copied across the package from `\library\pander` into my new R v3.2.0 installation. So far it seems to be working fine.

I've had a go at doing this for the `sparkr` package, but unfortunately it requires a more recent build of R. You might find that R v3.1.3 will work, but I'm not able to test that on my machine.

Comment: How do I move to an earlier version of R?  Currently have 3.2 installed in which I am getting the error.

Comment: You should be able to install it from [link](http://cran.rstudio.com/) and select an earlier version from "Source code of older versions of R is available here.". You'll probably need to install `devtools` again in order to install packages from github. As I said, I tried R v3.1.2 and it worked for the `pander` package but not for `sparkr`, but R v3.1.3 may work for `sparkr`.

Comment: @ChrisP that sounds really strange. Can you please give some more details on that `pander` issue? I'm the maintainer and would love to understand what went wrong on your machine. Please submit a ticket on GitHub if you think it's something with the package: https://github.com/Rapporter/pander/issues

Comment: @daroczig - I had the same error message as @GaneshBhat. I'm fairly sure it wasn't a problem with `pander`. The problem was only when installing `pander` from Github, not CRAN. For your reference I was running devtools v1.7.0, Windows 7, R v3.2.0 and RStudio v0.99.386 (same problem in earlier verisons of Rstudio and R).